# How to access clipboard data programmatically in Android Q (10)?

Tags: android, android-10.0, clipboardmanager

As we know read data by Clipboard Manager in the background was stopped by Google in android Q, so I need anyway to paste data copied directly in edit text when a user returns to activity without user make a paste and without paste button.

The issue is that trying to read the data with `getPrimaryClip()` returns `null`.

```java
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_copy_and_paste);

           ed_editText = findViewById(R.id.ed_editText);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
           getCopy()
        }

    private void getCopy() {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                if (clipboard != null && clipboard.hasPrimaryClip() && clipboard.getPrimaryClip() != null) {
                    CharSequence clip = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).coerceToText(CopyAndPasteActivity.this).toString();
                        ed_editText.setText(clip.toString());
                }      

    }
```

XML

```
      <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ed_editText"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@null" >
                    <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should access the clipboard in [`Window.Callback.onWindowFocusChanged(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29), as that is the moment at which you gain input focus, which is required to read the clipboard in Android 10 (Q).  You don't yet necessarily have input focus in `onResume`.

Comment: what about Android 11 ? can you please give answer for Android 11 as well?

Comment: @s4suryapal This should work on Android 10 and up, including Android 11.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is correct, but this is an extended version of it.

This will get the last copied item from the clipboard.

```java
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        boolean isAndroid10Plus = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q);

        if(!isAndroid10Plus) return;

        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
        String data = item.getText().toString();
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

That's it.

**Common use of clipboard:**

The way above will continuously get the clipboard data as long as the app is on focus, so you better add a boolean to check for clipboard data once. But if you're trying to show a dialog whenever the user pauses then resumes the activity (maybe copies a text from another app then goes back to your app), then better to add a boolean to check if you should show a dialog or not like this:

```
private boolean shouldCheckClipboard = true; // default should be true

@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        shouldCheckClipboard = true; // user has left the app, we should get the clipboard data when they're back
        super.onStop();
}

private void showDialog(String data){
shouldCheckClipboard = false; // stop asking for clipboard data
// handle data to show a dialog
}

@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        boolean isAndroid10Plus = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q);

        if(!(isAndroid10Plus || shouldCheckClipboard) return;

        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0); // get position 0 of the clipboard (last copied item)
        String data = item.getText().toString();
        showDialog(data); // pass clipboard data then show dialog
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```