# How to access the Clipboard data in Android 10?

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I was making an app that opens whenever someone copies a URL in phone. It worked fine in Android 9 and before but did not work in Android 10 because I was not able to access the Clipboard data. Can Anybody tell me the proper way of doing so

Comment: Can you please explain how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: The same question has been discussed here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903001/how-to-access-clipboard-data-programmatically-in-android-q-10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access clipboard data programmatically in Android Q (10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903001/how-to-access-clipboard-data-programmatically-in-android-q-10)